# choice user options as extend use case?

Tags: architecture, uml, software-design, use-case

I have big use case which is `Manage Orders`, I want to expand this use case to a more specific use cases.

when the user ask to manage the orders he can do many options which represent use cases, my questions is : is the big use case `Extends` the new use cases ?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The other way around. Specific sub use-cases `extend` the main use-case. Look at it this way: you always invoke the main use-case when you want to manage orders but the additional behavior may vary - `check order status` use-case extends the core functionality of the `manage orders` use-case. Same goes for the `order orders`. In you diagram the `extend` relation direction should be reversed.

Rule for usage `include` and `extend`: common parts that **always** present in the use-case can be extracted out (and optionally used by other use-cases) and `include`d by the larger use-case. Optional parts that may or may not present in the use-case should be extracted and they `extend` the larger use-case.

Answer (score 0):

As icepack explained, if you want to use `extend` then the relationship is drawn the other way around. But I am not sure I would use `extend` in this case.

In fact, a use case should always represent a real functionality. Here, `Check order status` and `Order orders` sure are use cases, but I am not sure `Manage orders` is. Are you sure it represents something on its own? Or is just a way of grouping the other two? In this second case, you should use packages.

To answer the question, imagine the scenario describing the content of your use case. If, for `Manage orders`, your scenario is little more than "choose between `Check order status` and `Order orders`", then `Manage orders` is not a use case.